# Trying to copy contents of array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to copy the contents from array a to array b. When I test within the function it seems to copy, but when I print out b in the main program, it shows 0s

```
void array_copy(int a[], int b[], int n) {

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    b = a;
    //printf("%d\n", *b);
    a++;
    b++;
}
```

and then when I try and print to test outside, I get 0s

```
printf("%d", *b);
```

Any ideas why I am getting 0 instead of what should be in there. (I have made sure array a does contain non zero values)

Comment: `b = a;` should be `*b = *a;`, or equivalently, `b[0] = a[0];` .

Comment: `*b = *a;` , and try `memcpy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = a;
```

This line makes the pointer `b` points to the same place where `a` points to. What you want (copying the contents) should be:

```
*b = *a;
```

Comment: Since they are passed as arrays and not pointers, I'd argue `b[j] = a[j];` is more correct, but that's probably just me being pedantic... (and who uses index `j` without first using index `i` ;-)

Comment: @John3136 That also works if `a++;b++;` is removed. And arrays decay to pointers when they are passed as function arguments. My answer is based on minimal modification of OP's code.

Comment: Not disputing your answer is 100% correct and fitting based on the source provided. It's more a comment on the OPs conventions

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
void array_copy(int a[], int b[], int n) 
{
    int j=0;
    for ( j = 0; j < n; j++) 
    {
        *b = *a; /*  * will give the value */
        printf("%d\n", *b);
        a++;
        b++;
    }
}

int main ( void )
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int b[5];
    array_copy (a, b, 5 );
    return ( 0 );
}
```